# Unable to access Amazon Associates Web Service using Java client

Tags: web-services

I am trying to access the Amazon Associates Web Service with secret key provided in the "java web services up and running by oreilly book" that is 1A67QRNF7AGRQ1XXMJ07 and i am getting the HTTP 400 Bad request as exception.

I am doing the examples provided in the above Oreilly book.

Can you guide me how can i access the Amazon Associates Web Service to search for a particular item.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to register for your own key.  That key, if it was shared at once is probably not valid anymore.

1. You need to create an account at http://aws.amazon.com - this is free.
2. Once you have created your account, you sign in at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home . Ignore the message to sign up to EC2, you don't need it.
3. Click on account->security credentials
4. Look down the page to 'Access Credentials'. Your access key id is displayed in the table under 'access key id'. Your private (secret) key can be displayed by clicking the 'show' link next to it.